# Ignore a link in parenthesis while trying to extract other links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract links from a `p` block but I'd like to ignore anything within parenthesis. For example,

```
<p> 
  Some text (even more text <a href='link_text'>link_text</a>) another link <a href='link_text2'>link_text2</a>
</p>
```

I would like to only select any links after what is in parenthesis so in the above case just the `link_text2` link. I currently grab the links using this...

```
 ps = content.find_all('p', recursive=False)
 for p in ps:
    as = p.find_all('a', recursive=False)
```

I think I have to use a regex but not sure how to incorporate it so that it ignores any links in parenthesis. This regex works to isolate anything in parenthesis - `\(.*?\)`.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can analyze the elements in `BeautifulSoup.contents` to find all `a` objects. The latter can then be filtered to ensure that surrounding content does not create a `(` and `)` pair:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def is_valid(ind:int, content:list, flag=False) -> bool:
   return not isinstance(content[ind], str) or (['(', ')'][flag] not in content[ind])

s = """
 <p> 
   Some text (even more text <a href='link_text'>link_text</a>) another link <a href='link_text2'>link_text2</a>
 </p>
"""
d = soup(s, 'html.parser').p.contents
l = [[i, a] for i, a in enumerate(d) if getattr(a, 'name', None) == 'a']
new_l = [a for i, a in l if (not i or i == len(d)-1) or (is_valid(i-1, d) and is_valid(i+1, d, True))]
```

Output:

```
[<a href="link_text2">link_text2</a>]
```

Comment: So ran into an issue - `hasattr(a, 'a')` - this seems like it should work but it doesn't just isolate a tags. If I change the sample to include `<b>test</b>` right before `(`, that gets picked up as a link as well. shouldn't hasattr filter to 'a' tags?

Comment: @pad11 Please see my recent edit. I, too, find it strange that `<b>test</b>` also yields true when its object is used in `hasattr(a, 'a')`. However, I replaced `hasattr` with `getattr` to inspect the value of the `name` attribute.

Comment: That does help! Don't hate me though :( So what I gave is more of a basic sample simply because I don't know how complex it can get. If the text within the parenthesis has more text and links, the checks on -1/+1 don't work as expected.

Comment: @pad11 No problem. Do you have an example along with your desired output?

Comment: I just want to completely ignore whatever is in the parenthesis as the links will never be relevant but I cannot determine ahead of time what will be in the parenthesis. It can be multiple links with text surrounding the links or cite references like this...
``` <p> 
   Some text <b>test</b>(even more text <a href='link_text'>link_text</a><a href='link_text'>link_text</a><sup class="reference"><a href='cite_text'>cite_text</a></sup> ) another link <a href='link_text2'>link_text2</a>
 </p>```

Comment: End up using a flag to keep track of when I'm within the parenthesis.